# How to fix WFS_ERR_INVALID_SERVPROV error

Tags: c#, cen-xfs

I found an Xfs wrapper in c# (class library) [here](https://github.com/Kelvinkins/CoreXfs/tree/main/CoreXfs). Created a test project and set up the windows registry with all the necessary information for the Xfs manager.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/XFS
[image: ![![enter image description here]

HKEY_USERS/.DEFAULT/XFS
[image]

Test program

[image: Test program]

When I press the Open button for the Card Reader, it gives an error -29.

Error code list

[image]

Please help what else can I do

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late answer.
Do you have any service provider in your local that's logical name is "IDC".
If you have this dll file, try copying this dll file to the directory where it works

Comment: Thanks for your reply. IDC is the logical name of the card reader and the dll of this device is present